# Create sub-menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have the following code;

```
      <!-- Primary navigation -->  
  <nav class="sixteen columns primary">
    <ul id="nav"><!-- This ID (nav) is used to identify which menu is used for the mobile menu -->  
        <?php

            $args = array(
                'menu' => 'main-menu',
                'echo' => false
            );

            echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $args ), '<a><li>');
        ?>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Which creates this code for my WordPress menu

---

```
nav class="sixteen columns primary">
ul id="nav"><!-- This ID (nav) is used to identify which menu is used for the mobile menu -->

li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-14"><a href="http://www.testsite123-abc.com/">Home</a></li>

li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="http://www.testsite123-abc.com/about-me/">About Me</a></li>
li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-17"><a href="http://www.testsite123-abc.com/portfolio/">Portfolio</a>

li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"><a href="http://www.testsite123-abc.com/portfolio/folio-1/">folio-1</a></li>

/li>

li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://www.testsite123-abc.com/contact-me/">Contact Me</a></li>
/ul>

/nav>

---
```

This works well on Wordpress and the [jsSelectNav](http://lukaszfiszer.github.io/selectnav.js/) mobile menu, but my problem is that the link folio-1 is a child page of Portfolio, but I think because of the strip_tags function the ul tags for it are stripped out, if I set them as not to be stripped out extraneous ones get added which prevent the menu from working as well.

Is there any way I can get this to work or is there other code that would do what I needed.

Thanks

PS tried and failed to add the output code in the end I had to add it as text without the opening < please feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

you want to create custom sub menu in wordpress, for that you need custom menu items in variable.

First get all menu item in single variable using **wp_get_nav_menu_items()** function.

after that you using the following function you can get html for you menu.

```
<?php
function generatePageTree($datas, $parent = 0, $depth=0)
{
    if($depth>1000) return ''; // Make sure not to have an endless recursion
    if($depth==1)
        $tree = '<ul class="sub_menu">';
    else
        $tree = '<ul>';
    for($i=0, $ni=count($datas); $i < $ni; $i++){
        if($datas[$i]->menu_item_parent == $parent){
            $tree .= '<li>';
            $tree .= '<a href="'.$datas[$i]->url.'">'.$datas[$i]->title.'</a>';
            $tree .= generatePageTree($datas, $datas[$i]->ID, $depth+1);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    $tree .= '</ul>';
    return $tree;
}
?>
```

Using the above code you can get html for custom menu.

also you can get more detail about here.

http://www.beingdevelopers.com/create-custom-sub-menu-wordpress/